# About Material UI date Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, calendar, react-calendar, mui-x-date-picker

I am using a date component of material ui, and i have an array that comes from the backend api where in which i have some dates marked as present or absent status, so i want to match that date with mui component's date and reflect background as green color when status is present and red color when status is absent.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DateCalendar } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DateCalendar';
import axios from 'axios';

function EmployeeAttendanceCalendar() {
  const [attendanceData, setAttendanceData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
  const base_url = process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchData = () => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    axios
      .get(`${base_url}/emp/attendance`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': token,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        // Assuming the response data contains attendance information
        setAttendanceData(response.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const customRenderCell = (date, view) => {
    const formattedDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
    const isSelected = selectedDate && formattedDate === selectedDate.toISOString().split('T')[0];

    const attendanceEntry = attendanceData.find((entry) => entry.date.split('T')[0] === formattedDate);

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: isSelected
            ? 'blue'
            : attendanceEntry
            ? attendanceEntry.presentStatus === 'present'
              ? 'green'
              : attendanceEntry.presentStatus === 'halfday'
              ? 'orange'
              : 'red'
            : 'transparent',
        }}
        onClick={() => handleDateClick(date)}
      >
        {date.getDate()}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const handleDateClick = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DateCalendar customRenderCell={customRenderCell} />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```